# CSS Having border around 2 divs

Tags: html, css, typo3

I'm using TYPO3 with a calendar extension (cal). It creates events and shows them as a list. Currently, it looks like that:

[image]

Now I want to have a border around the date, but just as big as the text.

This is the extension's template:

```
<div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="event-wrapper">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <div class="date-wrapper">
                <div class="date" title="###MICROFORMAT_START###" class="dtstart"><span class="borderspan">###STARTDATE###</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="image">###IMAGE###</div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <div class="time">###STARTTIME######ENDTIME###</div>
            <h3><!-- ###EVENT_LINK### start-->###TITLE###<!-- ###EVENT_LINK### end--></h3>
            <p>###DESCRIPTION###</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div with class "date" is the relevant part.

This template creates this code:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center" style="text-align:center">
        <div class="event-wrapper">
            <div class="img-wrapper">
                <div class="date-wrapper">
                    <div class="date" title="20170118T210000" class="dtstart"><span class="borderspan">
<div class="day">18.</div>
<div class="month">Januar</div></span>
</div>
                </div>
                <div class="image"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="text-wrapper">
                <div class="time">21:00 Uhr - 23:00 Uhr</div>
                <h3>Frankfurt/Main</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takim</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried to give the class "borderspan" a border, but this didn't worked and looked like this afterwards:

[image]

How can I have a border around the date?

Comment: Isn't it looks like `<div class="date" title="###MICROFORMAT_START###" class="dtstart">` has too much classes?

Comment: could you show your css?, because without css your question is too broad and may be evaluated as off-topic

Comment: I didn't post my css because I don't think it's really relevant since I only declared colors, fonts and stuff like that. I already have a working solution to my question.

Comment: It's great! congrat...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your date is a <div> element which is block element by default. Means it take up whole width available. We need to make it inline-block, so the width will be content related. Plus add some padding to make some space between the text and a border. I set the border width equal to your text-line width and color to match the text color. Take a look:

```
.date {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 7px solid #ea644f;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know it would be that simple... Worked great, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `::before` and `::after` like so:

```css
.date-wrapper {
  max-width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
}

.date::before,
.date::after {
  content: "";
  width: 1px;
  height: 25px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.date {
  margin: 25px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="date-wrapper">
  <div class="date" title="###MICROFORMAT_START###">
    <span class="borderspan">###STARTDATE###</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also notice (like @Banzay mentions) don't use `class=""` twice per element.

Comment: Lol, Ron, i misunderstood question, too. "I tried to give the class "borderspan" a border, but this didn't worked and looked like this afterwards:" - it seems that OP already created this effect, but he (or she) wanted something else. However, leave answer, it will be usefull for someone, i am sure. :)

Comment: I'm very sorry if my question wasn't clear enough... Thanks for your answer and your hint about the classes tho

Comment: @sinisake ow wauw, totally misunderstood the question :)